# Any OS X Whiteboard apps/software designed for large screen multi-monitor use?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, display, mac-pro, multi-touch

We're looking at upgrading our static whiteboards to interactive whiteboards/smartboards, and one option is simply to buy 1-3 large multi-touch displays and hook them up to a Mac Pro, and use some whiteboard software on them.

Anyone know of any such whiteboard software for Mac that is designed to be used in such a way - namely multi-monitor support, plus multi-touch support?